# GWT kind of thing in .NET

Tags: java, javascript, .net

Is there is any alternate of GWT in .Net. GWT is basically an API from Google which allows you to code in Java and when the application is deployed, the GWT cross-compiler translates the Java application to standalone JavaScript files that are optionally obfuscated and deeply optimized.

For more details visit :- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit

Comment: do you really need this in .Net?

Comment: @AdelBoutros got a project developed using GWT and we have to suggest its alternate solution in >net, wondering any thing such as this exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checkout [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/) but to be honest with you those kind of things don't get enough attention in the .NET world as this might be the case with GWT.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick google: [jsc](http://jsc.sourceforge.net/), [SharpKit](http://sharpkit.net/) and [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/).

However as JavaScript becomes more ubiquitous (and it will node.js etc) it may be worth investing the time to learn to code JavaScript natively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. There are some projects that try to do cross-compilation of C# to JavaScript (ScriptSharp, SharpKit), but I don't think it's the right way to do it.

I would suggest investing the time into embracing the web as it is and trying a MVC-like web framework (KnockoutJS, AngularJS, EmberJS, BackBone).